# Typescript: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
let statistics = this.video.getStatistics();

let currentLikeCount : number = statistics!.getLikeCount() ? statistics.getLikeCount() : 1;
```

However, I get the following error when compiling with Typescript

```
error TS2322: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

My conditional checks to see if the like count is null, and, if so, assigns it to a number, but typescript still complains about it possibly being null.

How to I properly assign the like count to a number?

Comment: What's the type of `getLikeCount` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way for TypeScript to know that `getLikeCount()` returns the same value every time it's called. There are lots of other ways to write this code in a way that doesn't invoke the function twice, e.g.:

```
statistics.getLikeCount() || 1
```

Or

```
const c = statistics.getLikeCount();
let c2 = c == null ? c : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for some clarification why the compiler still complains:

if you write the ternary statement as if/else, you get

```
if (statistics!.getLikeCount()) {
    currentLikeCount = statistics.getLikeCount();
} else {
    currentLikeCount = 1;
}
```

The TS Compiler evaluates the two calls to `getLikeCount()` independently and thus complains about possible null values.
Ryan's answer provides possible ways to get around this.